# Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView next and prev item event from button

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, carousel

```
Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView
```

Hello everyone, my goal is to scroll to the next or previous page CarouselView the index, using the arrow buttons forward and back arrow.
The problem is that I find online events to advance the index of CarouselView.
It's possible to do it ? Exist?
Thank you

GitHub open source project [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to Bind to the `Position` property of CarouselView.

The property is available [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView/blob/master/txt/src/carouselView/dev/Shared/CarouselView.cs) in github.

```
    public int Position
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(PositionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PositionProperty, value); }
    }
```

You can find a good sample of what you are trying to accomplish [here](https://xamarinhelp.com/carousel-view-page-indicators/).